# Not able to get testdata from xls, while running the selenium tests through "Executable Jar" file

Tags: java, excel, testng, executable-jar

I am running the selenium scripts by creating executable jar file using following code.

```
public class ExecutableRar {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    List<String> testFilesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    testFilesList.add("C:\\path to testng.xml file\\testng.xml");
    testng.setTestSuites(testFilesList);
    testng.setUseDefaultListeners(false);
    testng.addListener(tla); 
    testng.run();
   }
}
```

Also for executing the test cases I use testdata.xls. Whenever I execute any test, testdata.xls is required.

Following is the hierarchy of my project : [please click on the image to exapnd].

[image]

I have created executable jar file from eclipse ->Project -> Export ->as "Runnable jar file".

So when I execute the jar file, test case starts executing but could not able to find the testdata.xls file, So script terminates with failure.

**My Question is :**

What changes I need to do, so that my scripts will get test data from test data.xls, while executing the tests using jar file?

**Update** :- Adding screenshot after writing this code

```
public String getCellDataWithRowColAndSheetName(int col, int row, String sheetName) throws BiffException, IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("TestData/testdata.xls");
    if (inputStream == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to read excel spreadsheet from the jar");
    }
    Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputStream);
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
    Cell cell = sheet.getCell(col, row);
    return cell.getContents();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are using for reading your Excel spreadsheet.

For e.g., if you are using JXL, your code to read the excel spreadsheet would look like below

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("TestData/testdata.xls");
if (inputStream == null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to read excel spreadsheet from the jar");
}
jxl.Workbook workbook =  jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(inputStream);
```

The only change you would be doing is to change your code from reading a File to reading a InputStream from the classpath and then feeding it into the excel reading mechanism.

Comment: could you pls tell me how can I set classpath for excel file ?

Comment: You dont need to setup classpath for excel. Its available automatically. You can double check this by seeing your target/ folder. You should find your spreadsheet somewhere in there.

Comment: I am not sure what is the correct file path you are referring to. Also what is the generated exception ?

Comment: I was getting IllegalSateException but then I cleaned and rebuilt eclipse, now I am not getting exception but nothing is getting fetched from the testdata file.

Comment: TestData/testdata.xls this is the path I was referring to

Comment: Now again getting same exception, how i can send screenshot here ?

Comment: You may have to put your resources (TestData/testdata.xls in your case) under `src/main/resources`

Comment: Any solution if i do not have resources folder ?

Comment: There is no solution if you are not going to be doing that. The problem here is that your excel spreadsheet is not available in the classpath. Maven usually puts only those things that are within the `src/` folder as part of your classpath. Not much that can be done here.